# Searching Text for Members of an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a project I am currently working on, I have the following models:

```
Guest
    name: string

Episode
    title: string
    description: string

Appearance
    guest_id: integer
    episode_id: integer
```

As you can see, guests 'appear' on multiple episodes through the appearance table. When i retrieve the episodes, currently by RSS..I'd like to find a way to check its title and description for any members of the Guest table. If it finds a match, it would then build the association.

Normally, this would be very easy given a small number of guests but it seems wasteful to iterate through the entire collection of guests and check both the Title and Description fields of the Episode.

I can see this being a "solved problem" of sorts, but I have had issues finding a solution that takes into account the scaling implications of a very large number of guests or an increasing number of searched attributes (such as adding more fields to the Episode model to check).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your relationships configured properly:

```
descriptions = rss_items.map {|i| i.description}

Guest.includes(:episodes)
     .where(Episode.arel_table[:description].in(descriptions))
```

Where `Guest` has a `has_many :episodes, through: :appearances` and `has_many :appearances`.

Comment: does this return an ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Comment: Yes, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation.  The whole `Episode.arel_table[:name].in(descriptions)` thing just creates the clause for me.  `Episode.arel_table[:name].in(descriptions).to_sql` returns `"\"episodes\".\"description\" IN (<whatever values are in descriptions>)"`, which is passed to the `where` method call.